# how to handle http error response in ionic 3?

Tags: angular, ionic3

```
login(credentials) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.http.post(apiUrl+'loginjwt', credentials).subscribe(data => {
        this.Storage.set("Access_Token", data['token']);
        this.Storage.set("user", data["user"]).then(res => {
          this.events.publish('user:loggedin',
            {name: data['user']['first_name'] + ' ' + data['user']['last_name'],
              id: data['user']['_id']});
        }).catch((err) => {
          console.log("failed to store");
          console.log(err);
        });
      }, err => {
        reject();
      });
    });
  }

this.authServiceProvider.login(data).then((result) => {
      let newdata = {"username": user['email'], "password": newpass1.value};
      console.log(newdata);
      this.authServiceProvider.update_pass(newdata).then((result) => {
        if (result["message"]) alert("Password Update successfully!");
      }, (err) => {
        alert(err);
        return false;
      })
    },(err) => {
      alert("Password is not correct!");
    });
```

what I want to achieve is that alerting the user that the password is incorrect when the login failed. But I also got the HTTP error response alert:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pysBn.png)

how can I prevent the http alert showing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you try adding httpErrorResponse when catching the error, something like bellow :

```
this.http.post(apiUrl+'loginjwt', credentials).subscribe(data => {
        this.Storage.set("Access_Token", data['token']);
        this.Storage.set("user", data["user"]).then(res => {
          this.events.publish('user:loggedin',
            {name: data['user']['first_name'] + ' ' + data['user']['last_name'],
              id: data['user']['_id']});
        }).catch((err) => {
          console.log("failed to store");
          console.log(err);
        });
      }, (err : HttpErrorResponse) => {
          if (err.status == 400) {
            alert("BAD REQUEST!");
          } else if (err.status == 401) { 
            alert("password incorect!");
          } else {
            console.log(err);
            reject();
          }
      });
```